# Visual Studio 2012 не видит пути после обновления

Tags: include, visual-studio-2012, lib, settings

После обновления VS 2012 перестала видеть пути к библиотекам и проч. Я попытался настроить их, но, к сожалению, проблемы остались.
Например, у меня есть проект, который прекрасно работал раньше, но сейчас там всё сломалось:[image]
Вот те настройки подключения, которые я указал:

[image]

Вот структура и состав этих директорий:

[image]
[image]
[image]

При создании нового проекта выводит такие сообщения об ошибках:

[image]

Кроме того, я не нашёл, как делать глобальные (а не для отдельного проекта) настройки.
Поскольку именно с VS я практически не работал (но такая необходимость возникла) разобраться с подобными, несложными в общем, как я понимаю, вопросами, для меня несколько затруднительно. Т.о. буду оч. признателен за помощь.

Comment: Ну, вообще, как бы использование `stdio.h` в плюсах - не хорошо. Следует `cstdio`. Это раз. К тому же мешать ф-ции из `iostream` и `stdio` желательно не мешать, хотя и можно с осторожностью использовать вместе. Два - бывают проблемы с namespace. При переходе с одной версии на другую компилятора такое случается. Можно или вручную дописывать `std::` или использовать директиву `using`. По папкам - очень странно, тем более, что уже давно никто диски `A:` и `B:` не использует, т.к. это были зарезервированные под флоппи-приводы буквы.

Answer (score 3):

Проблема решена. Суть была в том, что:
До обновления VS находилась здесь: 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0
после инсталляции уже почему-то здесь:
B:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0
файлы, пути к которым оказались битыми, остались в прежнем месте, т.е., здесь:
c:\Program Files (x86)\VC\
уж не знаю, каким образом это всё происходит и как это можно было предположить, но, тем не менее, реальность оказалась именно таковой (hello, Microsoft!).
Т.о., решение оказалось чисто эмпирическим.
1. Постараемся найти потерянные файлы на диске, где ДО обновления была проинсталлирована программа:

[image]

2. Скопируем их в директорию, где программа проинсталлирована сейчас:

[image]

3. Открываем какой-нибудь проект со ссылками на файлы, пути к которым оказались битыми после обновления:

[image]

Всё ОК.